# How do I async on_status from tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy, discord.py

The error I'm getting is:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'StdOutListener.on_status' was never awaited
if self.on_status(status) is False:
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

My stdOutListener looks like this:

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

async def on_status(self, status):
    channel = await bot.get_channel(64970710814)
    await channel.send(status.text)
```

I understand that I need to get on_status called async'd, but how do I do this? I've tried awaiting most of the things inside on_status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy doesn't yet have asyncio support. For that, see https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/732.

Instead, you can use the `is_async` parameter to run the stream in a separate thread.
See https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html#async-streaming.