# How to authenticate Tweepy Application to tweet via discord

Tags: twitter, discord, discord.py, tweepy

I am currently developing a discord bot that can post tweets and more. The whole code is basically done all I need to do now is make the user authenticate the app so the bot can post tweets. I searched everywhere and I don't have any idea on how to do it. My goal is to have multiple users in a discord chat use the bot at the same time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using tweepy with discord.py to post tweets to a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61535485/using-tweepy-with-discord-py-to-post-tweets-to-a-specific-channel)

Comment: if you need access to a "twitter bot account" you need to go on twitter developer hub 
https://developer.twitter.com compile the form, and after from here create an app

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want your bot to have control multiple user's API ?

If so,

Have the user inputs their credentials using a command, (best would be by DM, like ?api XXXXXX)
store this credentials into a database and have your API Caller lookup for a specific API credentials within your DB.